# Any downside to never creating ObjC files but always creating ObjC++ files instead?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, objective-c++

By default Xcode creates both an .h and and an .m file when you ask for a new ObjC class.
Everything works fine until you need to refer to any C++ file elsewhere in your project and start #import ing it into either your .h or .m file

At that point, the ObjC compiler gest utterly confused and throws mountains of parsing errors, and you the user (that is to say: me) get even more confused until such time it hits me: of course I should make that file an ObjC++ file instead.

The options are:

1. tell Xcode that this particular file, even though it is a .m file
   really is an ObjC++ file, or
2. rename that file to .mm.

The first option is not very palatable to me, because that file really *is* ObjC++ regardless of the what the project thinks it is.

The second option is not good either as it screws up the Git repo which then 'forgets' that there used to be another .m file which really is the history of this 'new' .mm file.

So I have decided from now on to always rename any .m file that Xcode creates for me to .mm first thing after creating it so that I won't loose the history.

It has worked well for me so far, but I have this slight worry in my head, that there might be some corner case where I would really want to have an ObjC file and not an ObjC++ file.

What would those corner cases be? Anyone is aware of any ObjC++ file which happens to NOT contain any C++ reference but would choke the ObjC compiler in some way, just by virtue of being an .mm file?

And if there are no downside, why not just deprecate the use of .m forever and stick to .mm instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no downside, although there are two methods created on behalf of you (`.cxx_construct` and `.cxx_destruct`), but they are only used for crafting and destroying C++ objects when you create/dealloc an instance. If your class has no C++ members, these functions do nothing and add only an really extremely low overhead. Otherwise, you still have C functions generated for your Objective-C methods, not C++ functions.

Answer (score 3):

Parsing C++ is much slower than parsing ObjC, so ObjC++ files have significantly longer compile times. I'm not certain if this overhead will apply to ObjC++ files that contain no C++, but it would make a certain amount of sense that it's harder to parse just because the compiler needs to look for C++ constructs.

Also, the C++ type system has a few slightly different rules from C, that are applied to ObjC/C code in a C++ file as well. I don't recall the details, but it's not going to be harmful; just might require a few extra casts.

Answer (score 2):

Create an Objective-C++ file template so you get a .mm file instead of a .m file when you create a new file. Make a copy of Apple's Objective-C class templates and rename the .m files to .mm. More detailed information on creating Xcode 4 file templates is available in the following article:

[Creating Custom Xcode 4 File Templates](http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/11/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/)

Comment: That was an excellent advice. Any tip to avoid my new .mm template being overriden/destroyed at the next Xcode update?

Comment: Placing the template in the user templates folder, whose location is mentioned in the article I linked to, should be sufficient to prevent your template from being overwritten in future Xcode updates.

Comment: Oh my! Just overlooked that bit. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Language incompatibilities aside, one reason to avoid an entirely .mm project is that you might end up being tempted to start sections of your methods in c++, which will result in a project written in a (relatively obscure) hybrid of two languages, and will only be understood by people who know both. (I have done this before)

A nice way to avoid cluttering your obj-c headers with c++ is to declare instance variables in your implementation file (which is allowed as of  xcode 4.2/clang 3.0, possibly earlier). Eg:

```
@implementation MyClass {
    std::vector<int> myVector;
}
```

This helps to keep the points of contact between objective-c and c++ minimised.

Answer (score 1):

I use .mm file exclusively for my iOS code and have never had any issues.  Yes, my compiles are a little slower in that a clean compile takes 15 seconds vs 10 seconds.  At least on a iMac, it's not significant.